# Finding necessary nodes with rvest: all attempts result in {xml_missing}

Tags: html, r, xml, xpath, rvest

I am trying to scrape my own LinkedIn page for data to later put into an Rmarkdown resume.

I started out with [this gist](https://gist.github.com/daattali/3868f67e60f477c8c0f0). However, it is 2 years old, and doesn't work anymore.
This segment seems to be working:

```
user_url <- "https://www.linkedin.com/in/___yourprofilepagehere____/"

username <- 'your_login'
password <- 'your_password'

library(rvest)   

linkedin_url <- "https://linkedin.com/"
pgsession <- html_session(linkedin_url) 
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                          session_key = username, 
                          session_password = password)

submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)

pgsession <- jump_to(pgsession, user_url)
page_html <- read_html(pgsession)
```

Inspecting `page_html` with `html_text()` tells us that the needed information is in the object.
However, I have no idea which nodes to call to extract that data. Original code isn't working anymore.
I tried SelectorGadget plugin for Chrome, as well as inspecting the page to find a relevant CSS node or an xpath, but every attempt results in this:

`{xml_missing}
<NA>`

E.g. SelectorGadget seems to be identifying this as a node for position titles: `.pv-position-entity h3`

```
page_html %>% html_node('.pv-position-entity h3')
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

Are there steps I'm missing here? Can anyone help please?
Thank you!

Comment: `user_url <- "https://www.linkedin.com/in/___yourprofilepagehere____/"

username <- 'your_login'
password <- 'your_password'

library(rvest)   

linkedin_url <- "https://linkedin.com/"
pgsession <- html_session(linkedin_url) 
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                          session_key = username, 
                          session_password = password)

pgsession<-submit_form(pgsession, filled_form) ## CHECK THIS CODE

pgsession <- jump_to(pgsession, user_url)
page_html <- read_html(pgsession)`